# How can I allow relative paths to be set in my css with React Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm fairly new to Webpack so I hope this question is understandable, I've tried to format it to be easy to read.
I'm using webpack to build my react app and I have finally figured out how to output my image folder structure and have hit another road block.
I  hope you can help me.

Outputted `dist` folder structure below:
[image]

I'm not sure why but in development I have to reference `background-image` url paths in a specific way. Issue is after running `webpack`, my outputted distribution build doesn't seem to like that the image file paths aren't relative.

In development my css is set as so:
`background: url('/img/site/placeholder.jpg');`
The build works fine in development but in production the image file is not found:
`GET file:///img/site/placeholder.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I can update the minified `bundle.js` so the css uses relative paths like so:
`background: url('./img/site/placeholder.jpg');`
This works only in production and not in development.

If I run `webpack` to output my React build for distribution with the relative path(`./img/`) in the css, I get this error:
`ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./scss/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/site/placeholder.jpg' in '/Users/moehammo/Documents/_Moe/00_MHC/conceptual_website_react/scss'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./scss/styles.scss 6:6248-6285
 @ ./scss/styles.scss
 @ ./index.js`

I've tried using `publicPath: "./"` in my `webpack.config.js` file but it throws my build out and I think I might be implementing it incorrectly. What am I missing in this conundrum?

My `webpack.config.js` file below:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const sass = require('node-sass');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets:['env','react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].[ext]'
            }
          }]
     }
    ],
    loaders: [
     { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' }
     // other loaders
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Are u using `webpack-dev-server` for development?

Comment: Yes, I am using `webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: My suggestion is to change the relative url from `./img/site/placeholder.jpg` -> `../img/site/placeholder.jpg`, i dont even think your file loader can work based on your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be using `url-loader` which is going to convert the file into a base64 string which will be applied directly into your image file when needed.

```
// regular js file
import img from './image.png'
console.log(img);

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you want to continue with `file-loader` try working with the outputPath property on the loader config in order to match the location of the production build folder. It's likely your production app is trying to access a file that doesn't exist in your "dist" folder.

```
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    outputPath: 'images/'
  }
}
```